# Не работают параметры при вставке Youtube-видео через iframe

Tags: html, api, youtube

Сейчас перестали работать параметры при вставке видео через iframe: autoplay, rel, show и др. Появились какие-то новые изменения?

```html
<iframe class='video' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/lkPJCEqiEVA?autoplay=1&rel=0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe width="1920" height="1009" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/lkPJCEqiEVA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe class='video' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/lkPJCEqiEVA?autoplay=1&mute=1' allow="autoplay" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Для меня это тоже больная тема. В интернете много информации, что надо выключать звук добавлением `mute=1` но, к сожалению у меня на мобильном браузере данный код не срабатывает на автозапуск. Обратите внимание, что так же обязательно нужно добавлять `allow="autoplay"` что бы код был рабочим.

Одно рабочее решение я находил, но оно противоречит политике youtube: [автозапуск с применением `opacity:1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53751544/20631404)